# c++ priority_queue push/emplace without temporary object creation

Tags: c++, performance, stl, containers, copy-constructor

I have learned that `emplace_back` method pushes objects into vector without temporary object creation. However, I could not find a way of achieving this for priority_queue either using `push` or `emplace`. Is there an efficient way to achieve this? or using boost's shared_ptr like containers is good in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't follow.  `std::priority_queue::emplace` should forward its arguments underlying container `emplace_back`.  Which compiler/version are you using?  Note, while temporaries aren't created, there is a lot of swapping that is going to happen to maintain the heap.

Comment: then, do you know what is the most efficient way of playing with stl containers. i.e. push, pop, etc. Is Boost the best when it comes to performance?

Comment: @IanDecks Huh? You need a priority queue based on a heap (O(logn) insertion and removal, no update of priorities), use `std::priority_queue`, you want to push things into it without creating temporaries, use `emplace` instead of `push`. So what? Want to do something totally different, then do something totally different and forget about `std::priority_queue`.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::priority_queue` is just a container adapter wrapping an underlying container (`std::vector` by default) with heap operations. So in order to `push` something into it without creating a temporary, then [`std::priority_queue::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/emplace) is exactly what you want to use.

Of course you cannot emplace anything into the queue at an arbitrary position (and your pushed element doesn't neccessarily end up at the end of the container), because it is a priority queue maintaining and internal order. But well, if that's what you want to do, you picked the wrong container (or container adapter), anyway.

And no, rarely is a `shared_ptr` a viable alternative if it is just about performance and not about lifetime management. Either you need dynamic memory allocation or not, so that won't be an option, especially in C++11.